# Install MongoDB with Homebrew and /data/db clarifications

Tags: mongodb, path, installation, homebrew

I am just starting with MongoDB and I am trying to figure out how to set it up properly. What I did is simply install it with **Homebrew** and created the folder **/data/db** as it is specified in the documentation.

The thing I got confused about was caused by this paragraph from the documentation:

> Run without specifying paths
>
> If your system PATH variable includes the location of the mongod
>   binary and if you use the default data directory (i.e., /data/db),
>   simply enter mongod at the system prompt:

I don't see the path to the directory mongodb in my PATH variable. But since I am not sure how Homebrew is handling that, I don't know whether I should add it by myself. In the documentation this step is added only when you would install Mongo manually.

The other thing I am uncertain about is where the **/data/db** folder should reside. So far I have it at root level, after I ran:

```
mkdir -p /data/db
```

Should it be somewhere inside the directory mongodb?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It installs by default at root level. Theres no need to move it into a mongodb directory.

Answer (score 0):

- Default installations make folder in /var/lib/mongod

  - paths are defines in /etc/mongo.conf

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows system then you have to set in classpath like

> C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

and data/db folder you have to create in Root drive or C drive.In this folder your all databases will be stored.